# Attributes set on Angular 5 Component host element not taking effect within jsPlumb

Tags: javascript, css, angular, jsplumb

I am working on my very first Angular >2 application and building it from scratch. I'm trying to draw flow charts on my application using jsPlumb. I'm stuck on the problem where when I set the component host element as the source and destination of my jsPlumb connections, the connector is not getting rendered (the corresponding svg is not getting created).

Following is my code - 
I call a REST with returns an array of items. I'm rendering these items onto my "Canvas" like so (addNodeToCanvas is called within a loop) -

```
addNodeToCanvas(card) {
    const factory = this.ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CardComponent);
    const ref = this.cardDontainer.createComponent(factory);
    ref.location.nativeElement.id = card.uuid; 
    ref.instance.cardData = card;
}
```

Note, in line 4, I am setting the unique identifier of the object as the DOM element's ID, which can be referenced by jsPlumb to create connections. When I run the application, I see a list of rendered DOM similar to the below -

```
<card _nghost-c4="" id="6c7e7bd4-200f-4b8b-8492-a59fb8809819" class="ng-star-inserted">
    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="item">
        Hi! I'm a node. My name is Dest 1.
    </div>
</card>
```

Once the elements have been added to the DOM, I create connection like so -

```
for (let c in cards) {
    this.jsPlumbInstance.draggable(cards[c].uuid);
}
for(let e in edges) {
    this.jsPlumbInstance.connect({
        source: edges[e].source,
        target: edges[e].destination,
    }, routeConnectionSettings);
}
```

Now the problem I'm facing is, when jsPlumb looks for the element card#6c7e7bd4-200f-4b8b-8492-a59fb8809819 (for example), its not able to find this element on the DOM tree and its not creating the connections.

Couple of this I noticed - 
When setting the ID on a div instead of on the component selector, everything works fine and the diagram is created without any issues.
Similarly, when I set a style to the component selector within a CSS file, the styles also don't seem to take effect.

Is this because component selectors are muted in some way that it cannot be accessed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

This is my JSON for ref -

```
"edges": [
    {
        "uuid": "dcc1151f-4668-4b3a-bbce-bc473545fcd7",
        "source": "770a7359-d8cf-4803-9901-0383a8d080f2",
        "destination": "6c7e7bd4-200f-4b8b-8492-a59fb8809819"
    }
],
"cards": [
    {
        "uuid": "6c7e7bd4-200f-4b8b-8492-a59fb8809819",
        "name": "Dest 1",
        "type": "DESTINATION"
    },
    {
        "uuid": "770a7359-d8cf-4803-9901-0383a8d080f2",
        "name": "Src 1",
        "type": "SOURCE"
    }
]
```

Comment: Try setting `:host{display: block;}` , you can not directly access selector of template as it's not in the component scope to apply CSS.  `:host` will apply your css to component selector.

Comment: That was exactly what I wanted. Setting :host fixed the problem I had. Thanks. Please post your comment as an answer so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `:host{display: block;}` will solve the problem.

You can not directly access selector of template as it's not in the component scope to apply CSS.

> The :host selector is the only way to target the host element. You
>   can't reach the host element from inside the component with other
>   selectors because it's not part of the component's own template. The
>   host element is in a parent component's template.

Angular Docs: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#host